# Ubuntu 18 Boot time is too long

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, services

My Ubuntu is taking too much boot time. Below is details

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain

The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @48.421s
└─multi-user.target @48.421s
  └─mysql.service @31.396s +10.665s
    └─network.target @31.396s
      └─NetworkManager.service @27.448s +3.946s
        └─dbus.service @27.050s
          └─basic.target @27.027s
            └─sockets.target @27.027s
              └─snapd.socket @26.954s +72ms
                └─sysinit.target @26.953s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @26.800s +152ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @26.295s +496ms
                      └─local-fs.target @26.292s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @39.370s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @37.513s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @4.757s
                              └─keyboard-setup.service @2.515s +2.242s
                                └─systemd-journald.socket @2.514s
                                  └─system.slice @2.514s
                                    └─-.slice @2.512s
```

and one more

```
systemd-analyze blame

 22.760s dev-sda7.device
 21.089s systemd-journal-flush.service
 17.017s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 12.578s systemd-udevd.service
 12.280s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
 12.259s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
 12.040s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
 10.665s mysql.service
  8.305s plymouth-start.service
  5.958s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  3.946s NetworkManager.service
  3.375s snapd.service
  3.125s udisks2.service
  ..................
```

Looks like `dev-sda7.device` is creating problem. Please guide me how to minimize the boot time.

Comment: A boot time of 48 second is quite good - 10 years ago, boot took 2-3 minutes. Did you notice that one item in your critical chain is lengthening boot by over 10 seconds? 'blame' items may not be on the critical chain, and may not be lengthening boot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I was trying to enable hibernate so I increase swap partition size from 2 GB to 16 GB (RAM 16 GB) after that my boot time was slow. now my question is that can it be a reason, because I think i also changed some more setting but not remembered correctly.
My old boot time was arround 10-15 sec

Comment: Probably the old swap GUID is still in the fstab and I bet swap is sda7.